# Given two point sets A and B, how do you find the point in A farthest away from B?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Does anybody know of an efficient algorithm which solves the following problem:

Given two disjoint point sets A, B of some metric space, find a point in A which maximizes the minimum distance to the closest point in B?

Comment: Not if we don't know anything more about the metric space.

Comment: This reminds me of the [diameter of a graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDiameter.html) (the idea of a maximum minimum).

Comment: @David Eisenstat Just assume that there is a distance oracle reporting the distance between two points in time O(1).

Comment: @user695652 There's a family of instances that forces queries to every A x B pair.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant on a nearest neighbor search; if you use a k-d tree to index B then a brute-force search through A would have an average runtime of n * log(m), where n is the number of points in A and m is the number of points in B.  If you cluster your points in A and test the clusters' centroids then you should be able to eliminate multiple points with one query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a particular algorithm. Given the problem I would start off attempting to see whether a binary chop could do the job.

To make progress needs more info though: you say "point A .. from B" as if B was a point, but B is a set of points - and indeed from the problem definition A and B could be the same set of points, or at least overlap..

In attempting to find a solution, recursion can be a help, too. That is, find a solution to f(n) given a solution to f(n-1).
By definition, if A is 1 point and B is too, then there is 1 known answer.

Can you then generalise a solution for n = 2

For example, solve if A is 2 points, B is one point. which A is further from B.

Once you have a solution where B is 1 point, you may be able to infer solutions for B = a set.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that given a metric f, you could use 1/f as a metric, then do a straightforward nearest neighbor search.  The only hangup I've got is whether 1/f satisfies the triangle inequality.